# Temporary Navigation bar not closing after clicking on a icon button reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I created a navigation bar from the material-ui website and I have a onClick that when the user clicks the icon button the navigation will get redirected to a new page and I would like for the navigation to close afterwards. I'v tried different things, but for some reason it will not close. 
The only thing that it does now is gets redirected to a new page and the navigation drawer continues to stay open.

I have a a function called handleDrawerClose() that closes the drawer, a const called navigation that creates the text and components and I created a const called handleNavigation that pushes the links, which makes the page redirect. Is there a way to call both of these someway. Thank you.

Below is my code:

```
    const navigation = [
        { to: '/', text: 'Upload', Icon: InboxIcon },
        { to: '/email', text: 'Send', Icon: MailIcon }
    ]

    const NavLinks = ({ links, onClick }) => {

        const _onClick = to => () => onClick(to);

        return (
            <List>
                {links.map(({ to, text, Icon }) => (
                    <ListItem key={to} button onClick={_onClick(to)}>
                        <ListItemIcon>
                            <Icon />
                        </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={text} />
                    </ListItem>
                ))}
            </List>
        )
    }

    const IconArrow = ({ onClick }) => {

        return (
            <IconButton onClick={onClick}>
                <ChevronLeftIcon />
            </IconButton>
        )
    }

    export default withRouter(({ history }) => {
        const classes = useStyles();
        const [_, { logout }] = useAppAuth();
        const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
        const [state, setState] = React.useState({
            left: false,
          });

        function handleDrawerOpen() {
            setOpen(true);
        }

        function handleDrawerClose() {
            setOpen(false);    
        }


        const handleNavigation = to => () => history.push(to);

    return (
            <Fragment>
                <AppBar position='static'>
                    <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
                        <IconButton
                            color='inherit'
                            edge='start'
                            aria-label='open menu drawer'
                            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
                        >
                            <MenuIcon />
                        </IconButton>

                        <Link to='/'>
                            <img alt='Logo' src={logo} className={classes.image} />
                        </Link>
                        <Typography variant='h6' className={classes.title}>
                            {process.env.REACT_APP_NAME}
                        </Typography>

                        <Tooltip title='Logout'>
                            <Link to='/login'>
                                <IconButton onClick={logout} className={classes.logout}>
                                    <LogoutIcon />
                                </IconButton>
                            </Link>
                        </Tooltip>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>

                <Drawer
                    className={classes.drawer}
                    variant='temporary'
                    anchor='left'
                    open={open}
                    >
                    <div className={classes.iconArrow}>
                        <IconArrow onClick={handleDrawerClose} />
                    </div>     

                    <Divider />

                    <NavLinks
                        links={navigation}
                        onClick={() => handleNavigation}
                    />
                </Drawer>
            </Fragment>
        )
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you just close it in the handler?

```
const handleNavigation = to => { 
  setOpen(false); // add this
  history.push(to);
}
```

Comment: Glad i could help! It would be nice if you could upvote my answer and mark it as the correct one, thank you! :)